# Following this simple diagram what wire goes where?

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

These are the available wires:

[image]

This is the diagram on how to connect them to 110v

[image]

And that's the plug I want to use with that fan.

[image]

Now the diagram seems clear:

Brown takes 1 line
black, white, yellow on line 2
red, orange, blue on insulate.

My questions are:

- Line 1/2 which one is black or white in my plug?
- Do I use all 3 wires (black, white, yellow) together or just pick 1?
- Does insulate mean the green wire in the plug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't tell you which is hot and which is neutral, so presumably you can use either black or white (hot/neutral) for Line 1 and Line 2.

Insulate means connect the three wires together (eg. in a wire nut) and **nowhere else** (insulated from everything else).

The green wire must be connected solidly to the metal housing somewhere appropriate, for safety against electrical shock. Have someone qualified have a gander at it before powering it up.

Comment: *The green wire should connect* -should+must

Comment: @Janka good point, made it stronger.

Comment: I see, so black/white doesnt matter, however i do need all 3 of the wires

Comment: That's why they are in the cord. Black and white for power and green for safety.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, no i mean the `black, white, yellow` from the diagram

Comment: Yes, they should be connected together. Someone edited the photos down in resolution so the diagram is no longer readable, unfortunately.

Comment: so i should take the green wire in the cord and connect it to the actual frame of the fan ?

Comment: Yes, probably there is an appropriate place to connect it. If none is obvious, contact the supplier.

Answer (score 1):

- brown wire to CORD LINE 1
- black,  white and yellow wires to CORD LINE 2
- red, orange,  and blue to each other only
- chassis of the motor to CORD GROUND which is green or bare

Since they're not asking for a neutral,  that means the white wire in the cord can go to either line 1 or 2, whichever.  The cord black is the other one.